# NFT marketplace images not retrieving

Tags: image, nft, marketplace, moralis, thirdweb

I am building an NFT marketplace using Thirdweb as the provider.

When I deploy my site locally the images for the NFTs show up perfectly but for some reason when I deploy my website with Netlify the images are not showing up.

Any clues, hints or leads are greatly appreciated. If I get an idea of why then I can usually figure out the rest.

If there is a certain section of code you would like me to post just say the word and I will post a screenshot. I will be checking this post regularly. Thank you to any kind souls who help me in this time of need

Answer (score 1):

Not being able to render the images points to a problem hitting the ipfs gateway which serves up the media files that have been pinned to ipfs.  To confirm this you might want to try and hit the URL directly.  In the case of thirdweb if you are using the thirdweb SDK the gateway would be "https://gateway.ipfscdn.io/ipfs/..."

Here is an example URI https://gateway.ipfscdn.io/ipfs/QmS9jCGH6Fnc8rQLcA6kZK5i2CCukyN4DSXhZGcDg5xpQd/0.png that you can confirm if it renders.

My suspicion is that there is something in your deployment config that needs to be tweaked to open up that link

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).